# Checking Characters Prior to String for Match

Tags: python, split

I am returning lines in a file that contain the string "bingo". However, I would like to exclude lines that contain "//" anywhere before "bingo" in the line because that means it is a comment. I am thinking to do this by splitting the line, and searching parts prior to the part containing "bingo" for "//" in them but I am not sure how to do this.

```
 for line in file:
    if re.search("bingo", line):
      for parts in line.split():
        if parts eq "bingo":
          #not sure how to do this
```

Comment: You could `split` on `bingo` and make sure the first part doesn't contain `//`; you could `split` on `//` and see if the first part contains `bingo`.

Comment: @ScottHunter That's actually perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the comment first before you search. To remove the comment, you can slice the string by the index of the first occurrence of `'//'`, which you can obtain with the `str.find` method. This method returns -1 when there is no match, but should not be consequential in your case since it happens to serve to chop off the trailing newline character that isn't needed for the search:

```
for line in file:
    if 'bingo' in line[:line.find('//')]:
        # code that handles the match
```